# Super simple trailing closure syntax in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, trailing

I am trying to follow the [example in the Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_161) for a trailing closure.

This is the function:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
    print("we do something here and then go back")//does not print
}
```

And I call it here.

```
        print("about to call function")//prints ok
        someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
            print("we did what was in the function and can now do something else")//does not print
        })
        print("after calling function")//prints ok
```

The function, however, is not getting called.  What is wrong with the above?

Here's the Apple example:

> func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
>       // function body goes here }
>
> // Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:
>
> someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
>       // closure's body goes here })

Comment: A closure is just a value. Just like any other value, you can "ignore" its existence and nothing would happen. Making anything happen would require you to actually use the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your example fixed:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
    print("we do something here and then go back")

    // don't forget to call the closure
    closure()
}


print("about to call function")

// call the function using trailing closure syntax
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    print("we did what was in the function and can now do something else")
}

print("after calling function")
```

**Output:**

> ```
> about to call function
> we do something here and then go back
> we did what was in the function and can now do something else
> after calling function
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Docs isn't very clear in explanation you need

```
print("1")
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {  // can be also  someFunctionThatTakesAClosure { without ()
    print("3") 

}
```

---

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) { 
   print("2") 

   /// do you job here and line blow will get you back
    closure()
}
```

the trailing closure is meant for completions like when you do a network request and finally return the response like this

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(completion:  @escaping ([String]) -> Void) { 
   print("inside the function body") 
   Api.getData { 
      completion(arr)
   }
}
```

And to call

```
print("Before calling the function")
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure { (arr) in
  print("Inside the function callback  / trailing closure " , arr)
}
print("After calling the function")
```

what you missed to read

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I saw that but read it as though you could use either one.  Thx for clarifying!  I upvoted answer.